# Destroy / Reset jquery-menu-aim

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, submenu

Working in a responsive layout, so I have two versions of a menu. I want to use menu-aim on the desktop version, but remove it on smaller screens.

Looking here, there appears to be a way to [kill the function](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/pull/41), so the hover states deactivate under a specified width, but I cannot get it to work. I have commented there as well for instruction.

This is what I am trying:

```
function menuDelay() {
    // Super cool delay menu
    if(isDesktop()) {
        $('.mainnav > li').each(function() {
        $menu = $(this).find('.menu-header ul');
        $menu.menuAim({
            activate: activateSubmenu,
            deactivate: deactivateSubmenu,

        }); 
    });
    }
}

function menuKill() {
    $('.mainnav > li').each(function() {
        $menu = $(this).find('.menu-header ul');
        $menu.menuAim.destroy;
    });
}
```

Where I am using .resize() to listen for screenWidth. If it's below a threshold, run menuKill().

Mainly I am unclear how to kill all functionality of menu-aim, but if possible this is not the proper way to structure this logic, I am open to any criticism there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@bobbyrenwick](https://github.com/bobbyrenwick), the call to destroy MenuAim is:

$menu.menuAim("destroy");

It's in the comments [here.](https://github.com/EDITD/jQuery-menu-aim/commit/1cdd47dae1ca5ec952b74367e7f5b7f4e59d7b64#commitcomment-10068542)